# Validate an arbitrary number of PowerShell script parameters

Tags: powershell

It is possible in PowerShell to validate the parameters passed to a script and also enables auto completion, as seen below:

`myscript.ps1`:

```
param([Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][String][ValidateSet('abc',
                                                        'def',
                                                        'ghi')] $argument
     )
```

But this only enables the auto completion for the first argument. I want number of "auto complete"-able parameters to be arbitrary.

Therefore after typing:

- `PS C:\> .\myscript.ps1 def` (additional white space at the end) and
- pressing tab, I want the possible parameters to be auto completed again `PS C:\> .\myscript.ps1 def abs`

How do I code this in the `param(...)` part?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do want to pass values as *individual arguments* separated *with whitespace*, use the `ValueFromRemainingArguments` parameter attribute:

```
param(
  [Parameter(ValueFromRemainingArguments)]
  [ValidateSet('abc', 'def', 'ghi')]
  [string[]] $argument
 )
```

Note that `$argument` is now an *array* of values, in which PowerShell collects all positional arguments for you.

The potential down-side is that this subjects *all* positional arguments to the validation, so if you also need to pass other arguments, you'll have to prefix them with the parameter name (e.g., `-foo bar`).

---

Therefore, consider using a single, *explicitly* array-valued parameter instead:

```
param(
      [ValidateSet('abc', 'def', 'ghi')] 
      [string[]] $argument
     )
```

That way, `$argument` will receive multiple values *if passed with `,` as the separator*, and in addition to tab-completing the 1st value, each additional one after typing `,` can be tab-completed too.

```
./myscript a<tab>  # -> ./myscript abc

./myscript abc, d<tab<  # -> ./myscript abc, def
```

Comment: My pleasure, @user69453; glad to hear it helped.